# How can I update my WAMS table?

Tags: c#, sql-update, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

Thinking that what I need to do to update a WAMS record is to select the record I want, then modify the member of the selected record that I want to change, and finally call Update on that record, I've got this code:

```
 public static async Task<bool> UpdateInvitation(string senderID, string readerName, string senderDeviceID)
 {
     try
     {
         IMobileServiceTable<WAMS_INVITATIONS> invitationsTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<WAMS_INVITATIONS>();
         MobileServiceTableQuery<WAMS_INVITATIONS> invitationRecordToUpdate =
               invitationsTable.Where(i => i.SenderID == senderID).
                                Where(i => i.ReaderName == readerName).
                                //Select(i => i.SenderDeviceID).
                                Take(1); // the query returns a List, but I only want 1 record (and it should only return 1)
         //invitationRecordToUpdate.SenderDeviceID = senderDeviceID; <-- "SenderDeviceID" not recognized
         await invitationsTable.UpdateAsync(invitationRecordToUpdate);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         return false;
     }
     return true; // If no exception, assume record was inserted successfully
 }
```

...but it won't even compile. The err msgs I get are:

1)
*The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IMobileServiceTable.Upd
ateAsync(PhoneApp.Data.WAMS_INVITATIONS)' has some invalid arguments*

...okay, but what are the invalid arguments?

2)
*Argument 1: cannot convert from 
'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTableQuery

> ' to 'PhoneApp.Data.WAMS_INVITATIONS'"*

I would expect invitationRecordToUpdate to contain all the members/columns of WAMS_INVITATIONS, 
including SenderDeviceID, but no...why? And more importantly, what is the canonical/preferred method 
(no pun intended) to update a WAMS record?

### UPDATE

(No pun intended, although this question does revolve around Updates)

Trying to use the suggested answer, this wont' compile:

```
invitationsTable.Where(i => i.SenderID == senderID && i.ReaderName ==  readerName).SingleOrDefault
();
```

(in the VS editor, the "SingleOrDefault" is redder than chairman Mao's book)

...and this:

```
await invitationsTable.UpdateAsync(invitationRecordToUpdate[0]);
```

...also does not compute, with: "*Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTableQuery'*"

### UPDATE 2

Changing it from:

```
IMobileServiceTable<TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS> invitationsTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS>();
```

...to this:

```
var invitationsTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS>();
```

...makes no difference (and it shouldn't - all that does is make the explicity data type implicit based on the type's constructor.

So my code is now:

```
public static async Task<bool> UpdateInvitation(string senderID, string readerName, string senderDeviceID)
{
    try
    {
        IMobileServiceTable<TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS> invitationsTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS>();

        MobileServiceTableQuery<TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS> invitationRecordToUpdate =
            invitationsTable.Where(i => i.SenderID == senderID).
                             Where(i => i.ReaderName == readerName).
                             Take(1);

        if (null != invitationRecordToUpdate)
        {
            //await invitationsTable.UpdateAsync(invitationRecordToUpdate[0]); //both of these fail...
            //await invitationsTable.UpdateAsync(invitationRecordToUpdate);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true; // If no exception, assume record was inserted successfully
}
```

...as you can see, I'm unable to UpdateAsync, as both ways of doing it (commented out) don't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update like this and show error:

```
public static async Task<bool> UpdateInvitation(string senderID, string readerName, string senderDeviceID)
    {
        try
        {
            IMobileServiceTable<TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS> invitationsTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS>();

            var invitationRecordToUpdate =
                invitationsTable.Where(i => i.SenderID == senderID).
                                 Where(i => i.ReaderName == readerName).
                                 Take(1).ToListAsync();

                await invitationsTable.UpdateAsync(invitationRecordToUpdate[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true; // If no exception, assume record was inserted successfully
    }
```

EDIT
I just checked my Windows stre app. I use this and everything is ok:

```
private IMobileServiceTable<Rating> RatingTable =
         App.MobileService.GetTable<Rating>();

    var list = await RatingTable.Where(p => p.Id == sel_item.Id && p.User == user).ToListAsync();
    vat item=list[0];
```

Comment: Err msg is: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<TaSLS_PhoneApp.TaSLs_Data.TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS>>'"

Comment: replace ToListAsync with ToCollectionView()

Comment: Perhaps very close; but I need to actually update the returned record, and the SenderDeviceID in the line to accomplish that is red/unrecognized yet:
                var invitationRecordToUpdate =
                    invitationsTable.Where(i => i.SenderID == senderID).
                                     Where(i => i.ReaderName == readerName).
                                     Take(1).ToCollectionView(); //ToListAsync();
                invitationRecordToUpdate.SenderDeviceID = senderDeviceID;
                await invitationsTable.UpdateAsync(invitationRecordToUpdate[0]);

Comment: Oh, okay, this worked:
invitationRecordToUpdate[0].SenderDeviceID = senderDeviceID;
So I will award you the 50 points now - thanks!

Comment: Ok I wait for my award. Now isn't come yet.

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I thought marking it as the correct answer would do that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

When return list just use first element:

```
       await invitationsTable.UpdateAsync(invitationRecordToUpdate[0]);
```

You can make better linq:

```
invitationsTable.Where(i => i.SenderID == senderID && i.ReaderName ==  readerName).SingleOrDefault();
```

Remember to chek item exist:

```
if(invitationRecordToUpdate!=null)
{//UPDATE }
```

**SingleOrDefault method:**

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

Comment: The suggestions don't work; I'm adding my results above, and adding a bounty, too.

Comment: Alas (as Jerry Pournelle is wont to say), I cannot bountify this until tomorrow...

Comment: SingleOrDefault return one element so you don't need to use [0] index, just put invitationRecordToUpdate. In other case when you use your query the query returns list so you need to use varible with index.

Comment: Using the index won't compile, nor does the "SingleOrDefault" with your LINQ, as I noted above (update to my original question). Passing invitationRecordToUpdate is what I originally did, but it causes the two err msgs noted. Note: Anybody who answers this, I'll give them a 50-point bounty even if they do so before I'm able to a[d,war]d the bounty (tomorrow).

Comment: The errors are explicitly shown in the original question (and its update).

Comment: Try to add .ToList() in your query.

Comment: That (ToListAsync(), which is what's available) gives me "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<TaSLS_PhoneApp.TaSLs_Data.TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS>>' to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTableQuery<TaSLS_PhoneApp.TaSLs_Data.TASLS_WAMS_INVITATIONS>'"

Comment: Give me one second I will check my projest who using Mobile Service and Edit my post.

Comment: That doesn't work, either; I updated my original question again with more detail.